# hover not working on div element with textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

without using z-index I couldn't get the div values while hover that element.

```
<div id="main" style="width:150px;height:150px;position:absolute;background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span id="test" onmouseover="return test();">helo</span></div> 
<textarea style="width:150px;height:150px;position:relative;background:none;"></textarea>

<script>
    function test(){
    alert('hi');    
    }
</script>
```

how to get that test id value when hover that text ( without giving z-index to textarea) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if that's what you're wanting to happen :

```js
var s_val = document.getElementById("span").innerHTML;
var tArea = document.getElementById("test");

tArea.addEventListener("mouseover", function test(){
    alert(s_val);    
    });
```

```css
#main {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#test {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  background:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span id="span">helo</span> 
</div> 

<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Just get the value of the `<span>` using the `innerHTML` event (stored into a var for better view) and call it on the `alert()`.